# Displaying links to files in tests annotations

Tags: java, testing, annotations, testng

Can anyone give me a hand please?

I have a file with sourse scenario and would like to attach the path to it and see it in test annotation and maybe in test reports. 
E.g.:

```
@Test(priority = 1, alwaysRun = true, description = "/resources/textExample.txt")
public void addAddressTest() {
}
```

Is there a way to do this using standard annotations? The main goal is to open the file by clicking it and to see the link to it  ("/resources/textExample.txt")) in my final reports. Could you please tell me how it can be made?

Comment: It looks like you're using [TestNG](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html) (according to annotation parameters), then why do you have [`junit`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) in tags?

Comment: Excuse me, tags have been edited.

Comment: what does the txt file contain? You want to use the String in your Test what is in Test's description?